# how to remove static methods or static initializes as part of code refactoring in java?

Tags: java, spring

```
private static TimedLruCache<String, List<ZoneCutoffInfoModel>> zoneCutoffCache = new TimedLruCache<String, List<ZoneCutoffInfoModel>>(
            200, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

I have started with code refactoring, Idea is to reduce the static code in the project. what is the best way to remove static code?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/why-static-bad-and-how-avoid

Comment: Not aware of any automated way of doing that. Search & replace `"static"` with `""` maybe. As long as the cache is member of a singleton bean it's effectively the same as a static field.

Comment: "hands on" approach might be, eventually, the best choice. Change your static to non-static without worrying about the caller. Then fix the compilation issues. Though, note that not all static is inherently bad. Static code in DAOs (such as in active entities pattern) is bad indeed, though in a mathematical functions library, or in a string manipulation library, it is an acceptable (and widely adopted) choice.

Answer (score 0):

Removing static code can be tricky.

I can suggest some I have been doing.

put the methods in singleton beans and

1.use a factory as a DI to inject instances so you don’t need a DI framework.

2.setup an injection framework like [google guice](https://github.com/google/guice) to inject your instances. 
I am working on play framework for this it has some unique way of request handling making everything much easier.

or Take a look at Spring IOC for Resource injection

-inesh